# while inserting data in SQLite :No such table exception

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into sqlite table but it is giving me exception no such exception.please check my code and let me what changes should i make?

```
     static Connection con;
     public static Connection getConnection()
     {
        try
       {
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/zack/another.db");
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
         System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN :: SqliteCon:"+e.getMessage());
        }
           return con;
      }
```

and here is my insert command file.

```
     public String execute()
     {
       BufferedReader br;
       try {
           Connection con = SqliteCon.getConnection();
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();          
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "/home/Zack/Desktop/session.csv"));
           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] value = line.split(","); // your seperator
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT into sessionTab values('jack','pass','NYC'")
            //later i will insert values from CSV file
            br.close();
           }
         } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in UploadData class");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      return SUCCESS;
     }
```

I also added jar file to WEB-INF/lib/ of my project

Comment: Go to `another.db` and verify `sessionTab` does exist or not. And post exception stacktrace output by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved this issue!!!switched from sqliteman to Firefox sqlite plugin and changed extension of db file from .db to .sqlite.